# How to specify a variable property for a javascript object when passing arguments to a jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am implementing [this jQuery image zoomer](http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/) on my site. The essence of how it works is I have HTML markup like so: ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ktNJ/))

```
<a class="zoom" href="bigimage.jpg">
    <img src="smallimage.jpg" />
</a>
```

I then need to activate the plugin like so: (note the plugin is invoked on the image's parent container, in this case the `<a>` tag, not the image itself)

```
$(function() {
    $('a.zoom').zoom({url: 'bigimage.jpg'});
});
```

As you can see I have specified the url to the big image in the activation code. Is there a way to obtain the big image url from the href of the image's parent, or perhaps a `data-bigimage` attribute in the html?

E.g something like.

```
$('a.zoom').zoom({
    url: $(this).attr('href') // or $(this).data('bigimage')
});
```

Which clearly doesn't work but hopefully indicates what is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin looks for a data-src attribute first if no url parameter is provided, so you can do it as follows : http://jsfiddle.net/3ktNJ/33/

Place the URL to the large image in the data-src attribute :

```
<a class="zoom">
    <img data-src="http://placekitten.com/400/600" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" />
</a>
<br>
<a class="zoom">
    <img data-src="http://placekitten.com/500/700" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" />
</a>
```

Call the function with no URL parameter :

```
$('a.zoom').zoom();
```

Comment: wow right you are. Strange that the author didn't seem to put that in the docs or readme

Comment: that got me too, so i came up with a bit of a wild (not so great) solution first! then i had a look through the source code and noticed that he's checking for a data-src in there =)

Answer (score 1):

If what you have there doesn't work, you may be able to try:

```
$(function(){
    $('a.zoom').each(function(){
        var thisURL = $(this).attr('href');
        $(this).zoom({url: thisURL});
    });
}
```

Your fiddle here updated: http://jsfiddle.net/3ktNJ/1/

**UPDATE** Per OP request, a small change has been made to the plugin.  This does not effect the plugin's normal usage:

This section has been edited:

```
if (!settings.url) {
    $urlElement = $source.find('img');
    if ($urlElement[0]) {
        settings.url = $urlElement.data('src') || $urlElement.attr('src');
    }
    if (!settings.url) {
        return;
    }
}
```

To this:  You'll notice I added an extra 'if' statement in here to walk around the URL manager.  I'm still not sure why the `!settings.url` says false, even when it's outputting a real URL string...  But this seems to work.

```
if (!settings.url) {
    if ($(target).attr('href')) {
        settings.url = $(target).attr('href');
    } else {
        $urlElement = $source.find('img');
        if ($urlElement[0]) {
            settings.url = $urlElement.data('src') || $urlElement.attr('src');
        }
        if (!settings.url) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Bwnk7/1/)  As an added bonus, specifically for your needs, you do not have to supply the small image's parent href source.  It will automatically grab it and use it if you do not supply a URL.  You will notice at the bottom of the fiddle that it is not sending any URL, but it is still working as planned.  Then if you remove the `href` in your `<a>`, it will work normally as before (which is not ideal anyways).

I hope this helps!

Comment: Indeed that does work but involves invoking the plugin for each instance of the markup which might hurt performance. Is there a way that only involves invoking it once?

Comment: @harryg Will you only have one image? Don't you need this for all images that have the class named `zoom`?

Comment: I might have multiple `zoom` containers. The original method will target all of these containers as once whilst your method loops through them one-by-one. It's not a bad solution but it would be nice to optimise.

Comment: @harryg Very true, it will loop through one by one at dom load.  I think this could only cause a problem when there are hundreds of images.  I will keep looking into it

Comment: @ActionDan Sorry, you're wrong. He's getting the URL of the `<a>` tag, not the image inside of it.

Comment: @harryg would you mind changing the `zoom` function a bit? We can add a line or two to include the tag name into the function?

Comment: No, happy to edit the plugin. It is only a small script and if it works out I can submit a pull request to the original developer!

Comment: @harryg I'll take a look into it and try to get back to you shortly.

Comment: @harryg It seems it's not accepting anything other than a string, although it is possible to USE a string.  I will be looking into it more, but the code has been pretty minimized and is hard to read through it.  Wish me luck!  It could be something you could ask the dev, to accept a variable that acts as a string.

Comment: Yeah it's annoying one can't target an attribute for the image URL. The plugin homepage is [here](http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/) and includes a link to the github page where there is unminified source. Thanks for your help so far anyway - your original solution will certainly work if we can't find another.

Comment: @harryg I've fixed the plugin for your needs and I believe it doesn't actually mess anything up.  You will have to use the non-minified version, because I did not update that one.  If you want to send the author this note, maybe he can accept it and minify it for you?

Comment: Many thanks for your help. As @nick mentioned in his answer, the plugin actually already searched for a `data-src` attribute for the big image. This was undocumented and only noticed by looking at the source.

Answer (score -1):

If I'm understanding the question correctly...you want to get the href of the parent div of the image...this should do the trick:

```
$("img").parent(".zoom").attr("href");
```

I added it to the top line of your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mN7m3/

Comment: No sorry I don't think you understood correctly. My question is asking how to pass the value of the `href` to the plugin invoking function.